# OS X server taking up tons of disk space

Tags: macos, server.app, disk-space

I'm running OS X Server, with the File Sharing, Time Machine and VPN services enabled. The `/Library/Server/ServerDocs` directory is taking up huge amounts of space.

[image: The <code>/Library/Server/ServerDocs</code> directory is taking up huge amounts of space.]

What does this directory do? Can it be deleted safely?

On a side note, many other subfolders of `/Library/Server/` are also pretty chunky, such as `Calendar and Contacts`, `Wiki`, `ProfileManager`, etc., even though those aren't service I've ever used on this Server.

Comment: Did you look inside the ServerDocs folder to see what is using the space? Similarly with the other folders? Apple quotes [10 GB of space](https://www.apple.com/osx/server/specs/) needed for Server, with "additional space" needed for "some features", so 22 GB doesn't seem outside the realm of possibility to me.

Comment: [Here's the directory listing of the ServerDocs (sorted by file size).](http://pastebin.com/iQx5VuvB) The files have all sorts of types and obscure names.

Comment: At least one of those files is an application. To answer your original question, no, deleting files out of `/Library` is almost never a good idea, unless you are absolutely positive that the files are no longer needed (either due to a removed application or that they are transient cache files that an application can recreate).

Comment: SC2Mod files are StarCraft 2 mod files, according to the internet.There seems to be no association with that file extension outside of StarCraft. Do you play StarCraft?

Comment: Yes, I suspect those are some kind of backups, but I don't know why server would have them.

Comment: I can't find a single reference to a `ServerDocs` folder, but Apple [does say](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202848) all service data is stored in `/Library/Server`. Assuming you have a good backup that includes that folder, you could try moving it elsewhere and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I have a time machine backup. I'll try deleting `ServerDocs` later and see what happens.

Comment: @AMomchilov I'm having the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve it? If not, did removing the contents of `ServerDocs` turn out to be safe?

Comment: I have since reinstalled OS X (for an unrelated reason) and had this issue go away. I'm not sure if it's safe to delete these, but if you have a backup, there's no harm in trying it

Comment: Ok, I've deleted most of the files in `ServerDocs`. Some of them I couldn't remove because it said were being used by OS, but that turned out to be around 20 MB total. Oh! And I stumbled upon https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202333 tech note, which instructs how to change server data storage path. I might set that to my 2TB drive if the directory continues to grow.

Answer (score 1):

This is an index of the files stored in any file share point which has "iOS" turned on as a protocol. Disabling iOS sharing will prevent this folder from filling up, though I've yet to find the "by the book" way to clear this folder.

Comment: Interesting. Mine was nearly 100GB. Not sure anyone knows how to connect to our fileshares via iOS so turning that off on the shares, but so far it hasn't cleared the data.